# Is typelist comcept still actual with variadic templates?

Tags: c++, typelist

Since C++14 has variadic template concept, it's not clear why do we ever should use `typeList`s as their defined by Alexandrescu. For instance, I mean the following:

```
template <class T, class U>
struct Typelist
{
    typedef T Head;
    typedef U Tail;
}
```

Comment: I'm unsure what change to variadic templates in C++14 you're referring to. They were born in C++11.

Comment: @chris: There's no mention of a change in C++14, just that they exist in that standard. Which is true.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, I suppose. It just seems like this was asked three years later than needed. The explicit mention of C++14 threw me off.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Do you personally use typeList concept in the production code? I just would like to know how that technique is actual with c++14's variadic templates.

Comment: @user3663882: Personally, no, I use variadic templates because the syntax is usually more straightforward, and I've no need to support pre-2011 compilers. But the question isn't objectively answerable; some people might prefer one option, others might prefer the other.

Comment: @MikeSeymour The thing that unclear to me is why someone should use typelists when we have the compiler supported feature. Alexandrescu itself wrote in his book that one of a few reasons we should use typelists was lacking of the compile-time support... It looks like old-fashion code to me now.

Comment: @user3663882 If you're referring to Alexandrescu's *Modern C++ Design*, it might look old-fashioned in parts because it is *is* old-fashioned in parts: was written 14 years ago.

Comment: Personal thoughts, typelist have extracted type, add type, remove duplicate type, reverse type, and other functions. These functions are useful in some circumstances (for example, mentioned in the book some design patterns). variadic template parameters allow creation typelist easier. Of course, if the variadic  template parameter can solve our problem, we naturally do not need typelist.

Comment: @MikeKinghan Yes, I reffered to that book. Actually, but his ideas about policies/policy-based design is still relevant in spite of being written 14 years ago...

Comment: @user3663882 I quite agree. That's why I said "in parts".